# Why is Weka3 giving me a "?" in the error column when running my test set on my trained model

Tags: weka

I have created a random forest regression model with a cross-validation 10-fold. I have saved the model and created a test set of 4 instances for predictions. The predictions print, but I get "?" in the error column and I am unsure why. Can anyone enlighten me on how to fix this?

[image: Evaluation output]

I had only 1 instance and thought if I added more the "?" would go away as I thought Weka did not like only doing one prediction. It did not work and I am unsure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the *actual* column, you will see that your *test* instances don't seem to have an actual class value (only question marks). If there is no ground truth to compare against, Weka cannot calculate statistics as it cannot determine whether the prediction was an error or not (hence the question mark in the *error* column).

At the bottom of the output, Weka tells you that 4 instances had a missing class value (`Ignored Class Unknown Instances`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would this be due to the training set not properly being normalized? My data is labeled supervised, but in Weka3 under the filter, there is no option under supervised for normalization or standardization only in the unsupervised. Could this have caused an issue and why the training and test sets are not recognizing the instances for prediction?

Comment: No, you need to make sure that your class attribute column in the test set has actual values listed and not just `?`. If you are applying filters, make sure that you do that using the FilteredClassifier meta-classifier in the Classify tab and not in the Preprocess tab. That way you can ensure that any filter that gets initialized with the training data applies the same settings to the test data. Whether a filter is supervised or unsupervised basically means that it either takes the class attribute into account or not.